# XOR reverse a string in objective-c get an error

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, xor

I want to use the following code to reverse a char * type string in objective-c:

```
- (char *)reverseString:(char *)aString
{

    unsigned long length = strlen(aString);
    int end = length - 1;
    int start = 0;
    while (start < end) {
        aString[start] ^= aString[end];
        aString[end] ^= aString[start];
        aString[start] ^= aString[end];

        ++start;
        --end;
    }

    return aString;
}
```

But I got an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this line

```
aString[start] ^= aString[end]
```

I googled and found people said I can't modify a literal string because it is readonly. I am new to C so I wonder what simple data type (no object) I can use in this example? I get the same error when I use (char []) aString to replace (char *) aString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're calling this like

```
[myObj reverseString:"foobar"];
```

The string `"foobar"` here is a constant literal string. Its type *should* be `const char *`, but because C is braindead, it's `char *`. But it's still constant, so any attempt to modify it is going to fail.

Declaring the method as taking `char[]` actually makes no difference whatsoever. When used as a parameter type, `char[]` is identical to `char*`.

You have two choices here. The first is to duplicate the string before passing it to the method. The second is to change the method to not modify its input string at all but instead to return a new string as output. Both can be accomplished using `strdup()`. Just remember that the string returned from `strdup()` will need to be `free()`'d later.